# cypress google map marker position drag not work on macOS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress

Im creating a drag test for a marker into google maps on react, like the follows

```
  cy.get('[style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"] > div > img')
  .move({ deltaX:20, deltaY: 20}).wait(600)
```

in Linux works fine but in macos, isn't work maybe im choosing bad the selector ? Please help me

Greetings